# jQuery PHP iFrame file upload returned data error

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I am using jQuery + PHP to upload files through a hidden iFrame.
I have it working and I have it working with uploading multiple files as well.

Summary:
I have a MAIN/parent our users will use to submit normal form input data with..
I have a second form under this MAIN form that is used just for uploading of any files.

When the user uploads some images..I return some data (either an error list.. or a list of successfully uploaded file back to the page).. so when the MAIN/parent form is submitted this inserted data will go along with the main form data (being saved to a database)

Here is my problem... while I can get some simple feedback added back to the page (using javascript to target a `<feedback></feedback>` element.. I can NOT insert any new elements into the MAIN form (as hidden fields).. I think I am having either a jQuery append/find syntax error or a pathing/scope issues.

To put the document structure into perspective:

Structure: (simplified a bit)

```
<div id="newMessage" style="width:100%;">

    <!-- MAIN/Parent form -->
    <form id="newMessage_form" name="newMessage_form" method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?mode=submit" onsubmit="return chkFrm(this)">

        <table id="newMessage_table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="border:0px solid; border-color:#ff0000;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">* Item Name:<br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    * Year:<br>                     
                    * Month:<br>                        
                    * Date:<br>                     
                </td>
            </tr>               

            <tr>
                <td valign="top">* Message:<br>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>                    
        <div style="text-align:center; padding-bottom:20px;padding-top:10px;">
            <input type="Submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" style="width:100px;">
        </div>

    </form>

    <div id="uploadContainer" style="margin-top:-40px;">

        <div id="feedback"></div>

        <div id="hidden_test"></div><!-- added to test jQuery return since I couldnt successfully target the parent form -->

        <iframe name="upload_iframe" src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>

        <!-- file upload submission form -->
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="handler.php" target="upload_iframe">
            <table id="uploads_table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="border:0px solid; border-color:#ff0000;">
                <tr>
                    <td id="uploads">                   
                        <!-- hidden until at least 1 file is added -->
                        <div id="moreUploads" style="display:none; margin:5px 0 10px 0;">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="attachMore">Add another file</a>
                        </div>

                        <div id="uploadContainer">
                            <input type="file" id="file1" name="file[]"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <!-- new/dynamically created browse/select buttons go here -->
                        <div id="moreImageUpload"></div>
                        <div id="upload_btn" style="margin:10px 0 0 0;">
                            <input type="Submit" name="upload_btn" id="upload_btn" value="Upload All" style="width:100px;">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

In my php file uploade handler script.. (handler.php) everything is working, exepct when I tried to echo back and into elements into MAIN/parent form (as hidden input fields)

```
echo '<script>
    //works general 'feedback' node
    parent.document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML="' . addslashes($name) . $returnerror .'";

    //doesnt work 
    $(this).parent("#hidden_test").append("<input type=\"file\" />");

    //also not working
    $(this).parent().parent("#newMessage_form").append("<input type=\"file\" />");

</script>';
```

can someone help me with my return jQuery targeting/pathing issue?

Trying to add to this element: `#hidden_test`  was just a test. (to see if I had a pathing issue)

I really need to add new (dynamic) elements to: `#newMessage_form`

Update:  when I was trying to view the source code using FireBug. (to see if I was getting my injected elements in the DOM anywhere..

I noticed an error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(this).parent("#hidden_test").append("<input type=\"file\" />");
```

But my other jQuery stuff works fine (in the main file)..

and the regular old javascript is executing just fine as well?  Do I need to inlcude jQuery lib into my hanlder.php file/script or something?

Comment: Do you have jQuery included in both the parent and child?

Comment: Thanks..  I have included the jQuery lib in the 'handler.php' file and this has seemed to clear up that error... 

Also to update.. (which I wasnt aware of)

adding: window.parent.document  as a second parameter here:

    $("#newMessage_table", window.parent.document).append("<input type=\"hidden\" />");

also seems to help with my pathing/scope issues!

I guess my only question (which may need a new post? not sure I know they run a tight ship around here..lol)

Comment: Yes - do a new question.

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard 
I did, thanks.. posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597559/editing-user-uploaded-files?noredirect=1#comment41809523_26597559