# Editing user uploaded files?

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload, editing

We have a form where user can submit a message,  as well as upload 1-10 files (not displayed in-line in the message, but as links at the bottom of the message).

This is all working fine so far... using two separate forms.

1 x form (MAIN/parent form) is the message details form (name. date, message..etc)

1 x form that is under this form, and if for handling the selected/uploading of user selected files.

This is done through a hidden iFrame and dedicated php script, and returns a list of uploaded file names/paths back to the MAIN/parent form (as hidden fields).. so when the MAIN/parent form is submitted.. all the data get saved to the database at one time, and the image/file uploading event/portion wont cause any loss of message data if there is timeout or other uploading error.

This is all working so far.

What I am not clear about or stuck on... is that for each message post the message 'owner/poster' can go back and edit the message..

This should include letting the user edit the files uploaded/attached to the post as well.
Which I'm not sure how I should be handling? or a nice and easy to do this?

I'm guessing I'll have to do the 'two form' approach I use for the initial posting/uploading of the message?.. but how can I pre-populate the file input fields?  DO I just pre-populate the value with the file name/path form the DB.. ?

Comment: Without more detail I would say that you should populate the form with values from the database.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard -

Sorry what other details would be more helpful?

My edit 'page' is already populating all normal input/text are fields with the data from the database.. and the user can edit as they see fit...  what I havent implemented yet if the file portion of this...

The user could have 1-10 file uploaded (per message)..

What do I pre-populate for this?  Do I still use normal input type='file' fields?  but then (pre)populate the value with the URL form the database?

Comment: hmm.. upon reading/researching, $_FILE is read only and can not be pre-populated?

I guess how do most forums and such handle this type of behavior?

If a user posts a message and upload an image.. and then come back later to edit this message.. how do they edit/delete or upload a new image in place of the uploads done previously?

Comment: They load in the existing data and then overwrite if they need to.

Comment: Load it in where? I guess I'm not following.

And how would that work with my existing project? (You dont need to provide code, just conversation to help grasp what I need to do)

My 'edit' page loads (which currently has no file upload anything in it).. where as my posting page has the two form approach (one main form and a secondary form that submits file uploads via hidden iFrame and php script.. I then return the 'file list' back into the main form as dynamically created/inserted hidden fields.. so it can be saved when the user submits the MAIN form/message)

Comment: You would load the data from the database into your form.

Comment: ---continue---

So to talk this out, my edit page loads.. I populate the MAIN form input/text area fields..and then..??  I should have my second upload form here as well I assume now? which will let the user upload files..

but not clear on best way to:

* display list of currently files upload/attached to message?
* have it so the user is overwritting these current files?

Comment: The queries on form re-submission would be UPDATE's (even if nothing was changed). Perhaps they could decide to replace, delete or add to the files. Given a choice you would then code accordingly.

Comment: That is what I am doing when in the edit page, I UPDATE the MAIN form details in the table.. but I still am not grasping how this works for the FILE upload portion.

When in edit mode... how are you suggesting I populate the currently upload files then?  as hidden fields int he MAIN form?

(how does that let the user know what files have been uploaded then?)

I cant pre-populate the FILE input fields as they are readonly I read.

Anyone have an example of uploading image on initial form submit, but then later lets the user edit these?